# Python3.9 cryptography.fernet error on import

Tags: python

My code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
File "c:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.8.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
File "c:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.8.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
File "c:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.8.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 242, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I am not sure what the cause is and I have tried a few methods including reinstalling cryptography

Comment: I suspect that you've saved your file with an inappropriate encoding: UTF-16 or UCS-2, perhaps.  UTF-8 is most likely what you want these days.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!!! I never changed encoding, but it was utf-16, anyway thank you

Comment: Hey @Ryder, did you fix the error? If so, could you write an answer to this question and mark it as accepted? That way others can see that it has already been answered (and possibly fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file encoding was incorrect, I had to change it to utf-8